# Get documents with the same parent

Tags: json, database, elasticsearch

OK, so I'm very new to ElasticSearch, and I need your help...

I have a type like:

```
|---------------------------
| PARENT_TYPE
|---------------------------
| some_field: string
| another_field: string
|---------------------------
```

And a child type like:

```
|---------------------------
| CHILD_TYPE
|---------------------------
| query_field: string
| another_query_field: string
| _parent: PARENT_TYPE
|---------------------------
```

So... in a few words: we have PARENT_TYPE documents with CHILD_TYPE children.

**What I want to do is:**

- Get all children (it'll most likely be only one) with a specific `query_field` value
- Get its parent
- Get all children of that specific parent

(or... to put it in another way: query CHILD_TYPEs by `query_field` and return all CHILD_TYPEs with the same parent).

---

**What I've done so far:**

(which just gets the CHILD_TYPEs i need by `query_field`. But still I'm missing the find-the-children-with-the-same-parent thing.

```
PUT ES/my_index/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 { "term" : {"query_field" : "word" }}, 
                 { "term" : {"another_query_field" : "en"}} 
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

So, how can that be done? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's what I've come up with.

I'm not sure whether it's the optimum solution (any suggestion is more than welcome), but it most definitely seems to be working...

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "type": "PARENT_TYPE", 
            "query": {
                "has_child": {
                    "type": "CHILD_TYPE",
                    "query": {
                        "filtered" : { 
                            "filter" : {
                                "bool" : {
                                    "must" : [
                                        { "term" : {"query_field" : "someValue" }}, 
                                        { "term" : {"another_query_field" : "yetAnotherValue"}} 
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```